# Why's 耳 (ear) the semantic component of 耽 (to delay, indulge; negligent)?

Tags: etymology

[CUHK](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%80%BD) doesn't appear to answer my question, or expatiate how 耳 semantically appertains 耽. What notions semantically link "本義為耳大下垂" with 耽?

> 從「耳」，「冘」聲，本義為耳大下垂。《說文》：「耳大垂也。从耳，冘聲。《詩》曰：士之耽兮。」《淮南子‧墬形訓》：「夸父耽耳，在其北方。」高誘注：「耽耳，耳垂在肩上。」

Axel Schuessler didn't list 耽 by itself on *ABC Etymological Dictionary of Old Chinese*  (2007), p 204. But apprise me if I overlooked it.

[image]

Comment: 冘：冘豫不定 (宋本廣韻 & 康熙字典). Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess 耳朵下垂 -> 下垂 -> 松弛垂坠 -> 拖延、延迟

https://www.pinshiwen.com/yuexie/shuojie/20200802282541.html

> “耽”是会意兼形声字。小篆，从耳，从冘（表示像担子一样下垂），会意耳大而下垂之意，冘兼表声。隶变后楷书写作“耽”。
>
> 《说文·耳部》：“耽，耳大垂也。从耳，冘声。《诗》曰：‘士之耽兮。’”（耽，耳朵大而下垂（至肩）。从耳，冘声。《诗经》说：“男人们多快乐啊。”）
>
> “耽”的本义为耳朵大而下垂。如《淮南子·地形》：“夸父耽耳，在其北方。”由耳朵下垂引申指拖延、延迟。如“耽搁”、“耽误”。通“酖”，指沉溺、迷恋。